# how to disable past date in semantic-ui-calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar, semantic-ui

I am trying to last one week to customize Semantic UI Calendar Disable past dates it is possible. I want like this I pasted example URL below. and my condition is if I select end date then if I open start date so whatever end date I have selected in start calendar after that day all days will be disabled.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/dAyzq/1/

```
$containerEventsAlerts.find('#rangeStart').calendar({
        type: 'date',
        maxDate: new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()),
        endCalendar: $containerEventsAlerts.find('#rangeEnd'),
        onChange: function(date, text, mode) {
            var $rangeEnd = $('#rangeEnd input');
            if (spa.isBlank($rangeEnd.val())) {
                //console.log($rangeEnd.val());
                $('#rangeEnd input').val(text);
            }
        },
        isDisabled: function(date, mode) {
            return true;
        },
        onHidden: function() {
            var $rangeStart = $('#rangeStart input');
            if (spa.isBlank($rangeStart.val())) {
                $rangeStart.val($('#rangeEnd input').val())
            }
        }
    });

    $containerEventsAlerts.find('#rangeEnd').calendar({
        type: 'date',
        maxDate: new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()),
        startCalendar: $containerEventsAlerts.find('#rangeStart'),
        onChange: function(date, text, mode) {
            var rangeStart = $('#rangeStart input');
            if (spa.isBlank(rangeStart.val())) {
                $('#rangeStart input').val(text);
            }
        },
        onHidden: function() {
            var $rangeEnd = $('#rangeEnd input');
            if (spa.isBlank($rangeEnd.val())) {
                $rangeEnd.val($('#rangeStart input').val())
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: create a fiddler link for your problem too.

Comment: hi  you got any solution for this please let me

Comment: I asked to add fiddler link for your problem.

Comment: below link PFA....    https://jsfiddle.net/rkrameshkumar71/2Lu8hjrb/

Comment: hi i have added jsfiddle link can any one solve my problem

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rkrameshkumar71/2Lu8hjrb/3/

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt solution for this in the library you are using. But there is a hack that can you do like below.

```
var today = new Date();
$('#rangestart').calendar({
  type: 'date',
  onChange: function(date, text, mode) {
    $('#rangeend').calendar({
      type: 'date',
      minDate: date
    })
  }
});
$('#rangeend').calendar({
  type: 'date',
  onChange: function(date, text, mode) {
    $('#rangestart').calendar({
      type: 'date',
      maxDate: date
    })
  }
});
```

There can be some more modifications required as per your need. But you have to do it all manually.